# put 2 elements same line

Tags: html, css

My code should be quite simple but I can't put the Sign in front of the button. it goes under it. I want the sign glyphicon on the right of the button with a small margin to it.

Any idea?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button">Validate</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What a lot of people aren't telling you is that Div is a `block` element, which means it  will go on a new line. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements , I'd also recommend putting the span containing the sign directly after the button, but within the button input group outer span.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: inline` in CSS.

Although I recommend putting your CSS in an external stylesheet.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group" style="display:inline;">
    <input />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button">Validate</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div  style="display:inline;">
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this css

```
.input-group{
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;
}
```

```css
.input-group{
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button">Validate</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Div goes on a new line

So, put the element on the same div

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button">Validate</button>
    </span>
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do not use

> display: inline

It's a bad practice, a div should divide elements. Use the tag span instead if you want a container.

Just like this below

```html
    <div class="form-group disp-inline">
      <span class="input-group">
        <input />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button">Validate</button>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span>
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use that code **sign** will come right side of the button:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button">Validate</button>
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And if you give any margin then please use the css for margin and add the class into it e.g:

```
<span class="margin-left-5"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
.margin-left-5{
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct and accepted answer. I commented on the OP post. This is the only answer that addresses that the span should be directly after the button and require no inline styling, just using default functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```css
.icon-button{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-left:5px;
}
.input-group{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button">Validate</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-button">
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign">sign</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```